# Making Media Library "Alternative Text" Field Required

Tags: admin, uploads, media-library

I'm looking to make the "Alternative Text" field required in the Media Library, just like the "Title" field above it.

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: The only features of that required field are the asterisk and being automatically filled with the filename if left empty...

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify, even more. I'd like the "Alternative Text" field to be mandatory when uploading an image to the Media Library.

Comment: A potential workaround would be to general the ALT text automatically (arguably a better user experience?) The code found on this page worked for me straight away:
https://wpkraken.io/blog/wordpress-images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make it work of sorts...

The requirement is not checked in the Media Library upload `/wp-admin/media-new.php`, but instead in the Media Upload thickbox iframe `/wp-admin/media-upload.php`.

[image]

---

The following is the *code that works* in the thickbox and *displays an alert box* making mandatory filling the Alt text field.
<sub>IMO, it won't be easy, but it can be adapted to work in the Upload New Media page (`/wp-admin/media-new.php`)...</sub>

```
add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup','wpse_55240_required_alt_text');
function wpse_55240_required_alt_text()
{
    ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".submit .savesend input").live("click", validateAltText);

            function validateAltText() {
                var value = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".image_alt input").val();

                if (value) 
                    return true;

                alert("Please fill the Alt text");
                return false;
            }

            $('.image_alt th label').each(function(i,e) {
                $('<span class="alignright"><abbr title="required" class="required">*</abbr></span>').prependTo(this);
            });

        });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Seems pretty hacky being client-side but if it's the same way the "Title" field is made required I guess that's the best implementation for now.

You say the above code can be "adapted" to work, but it seems to do exactly what I need out of the box. Just checking there are no further modifications?

Comment: @alecrust : I've rephrased my answer to make it clear what's working and where.