# Empty alt/title form check in media library

Tags: images

Many times, staff members of my site, are forgetting to alt/title tags once they upload images to the wp library.

Could you guys help me to figure out how to check and alert in case those forms are empty?

I found this script by brasofilo but it's from 2012 and looks like it is not working anymore.

[Making Media Library "Alternative Text" Field Required](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/making-media-library-alternative-text-field-required)

thanks !