# Call javascript function when add_attachment hook fires

Tags: javascript, hooks

I want to run a javascript function when the add_attachment hook fires. The following code does not interfere with uploading an image.

```
add_action('add_attachment', function( $post_ID ) {
    ?>
    <?php
});
```

When I add script tags and console.log("x"); I get an error message. The error message says "Bei dem Upload ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuche es später nochmal." See picture.

```
add_action('add_attachment', function( $post_ID ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("x");
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

**How can I avoid the error message and validate that my javascript code runs?**

[image: Error message]

Comment: `add_attachment` is a hook for PHP code, and in the context of the media library it happens in the background, so it’s not possible to run JavaScript on it. It wouldn’t make sense to. Are you really asking how to run JavaScript on that hook, or do you really just want to know how to run JS when uploading an image to the media library? It’s an important difference.

Comment: I want to know how to run JS when uploading an image to the media library. I want to use jQuery to make the caption field required. Similar to the first answer to this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/making-media-library-alternative-text-field-required . The hook used there doesn't fire when I upload a picture in my wordpress instance.